# how do I select on date equality in a mySQL query?

Tags: mysql, sql

I want to select rows from a table given a particular date of record in mysql

```
SELECT * from TABLENAME WHERE FROM_DATE='06/11/2012'
```

I am not getting anything useful.

Comment: ...and the question is? Which is your problem?

Comment: SELECT ... WHERE FROM_DATE >= '...' may be what you are asking for, but your question is very unclear...

Comment: Is `FROM_DATE` a varchar or date field?

Comment: It's not clear why you placed the oracle tag on this question, so I removed that tag. I also changed your title line to a queation. Accurate tagging helps you get an answer, and helps the community.

Comment: Re: *I am not getting anything useful* The question is still unclear. Does `from_date` contain a date only -or- a date and time? What is the actual result of the query an error, wrong records returned, ...?

Answer (score 3):

First of all, you should use the standard date format `Y-m-d` - otherwise you have to make some nasty queries and sorting is a real b*tch.

Using the standard date format you can easily do something like this:

`SELECT * FROM tablename WHERE from_date > '2012-06-11'`

Answer (score 2):

`DATE` comparisons are very likely what you want here.  If your from_date column has  the data type of `DATE`, then your code should be safe and robust if you do this:

```
WHERE from_date = STR_TO_DATE('06/11/2012', '%m/%d/%Y')
```

@Repox pointed out that you might consider putting your date literals in the canonical format '2012-06-11'. That's true, if you can do it. But STR_TO_DATE will do it for you if you need it to.  There's a list of the %x conversion items here. http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date-format

If you're using `DATETIME` data types, beware: comparisons are more complex than they seem.  `DATETIME` items are like floating point numbers: if one of them exactly equals another it's only by coincidence. That's because they represent moments (milliseconds) in time, not just days.

Presuming your from_date column has the `DATETIME` type, you should use

```
WHERE from_date >= STR_TO_DATE('06/11/2012', '%m/%d/%Y')
  AND from_date < STR_TO_DATE('06/11/2012', '%m/%d/%Y') + INTERVAL 1 DAY
```

This will catch all moments in time on the day you want, up to but not including the first moment of the next day.

If your from_date items are represented as character strings, take the trouble to convert them to `DATE` or `DATETIME` data types.  Seriously.  Your results will be far better.

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT * from TABLENAME WHERE FROM_DATE='2012/06/13'
```

Answer (score 0):

It would be better if you use the `DATE()` function of mysql

```
SELECT * FROM tablename WHERE DATE(from_date) > '2012-06-11'
```

Because, if the datatype of the from_date you set as TIMESTAMP or DATETIME then it won't return the correct results sometimes when you directly use the '>' symbol

Comment: True `date()` will truncate any time value. However it may also prevent the database from utilizing indexes on that column. Ollie's solution is preferable because it is index friendly.